# how to write messages iso 8583

Tags: payment, gateway, iso8583

I'm planning to make a gateway, I'm studying iso 8583 I'm in doubt, how to transform a credit card into an iso message? something like: card number, expiry date and cvc in an iso8583 message, another question and if a gateway really does this, does it transform a card into an iso message or does it do it another way? how does it work, thanks!

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. It is wise to read Code of Conduct before asking questions as at this moment your question is very broad and seeking generic knowledge without any visible effort on your side. It just doesn't comply. You might also want to consider not creating a system when having little understanding what it is actually supposed to be doing. Card data and authentication data is just a fraction of the authorization message. Apart from authorizations there are also other messages and some of them are not even associated with any transactions and contain no card data at all.

Answer (score 0):

I’m the maintainer of the Golang iso 8583 packages and I created a project that shows how to build payment gateway.

Here is the project repository: https://github.com/alovak/cardflow-playground

It has API where card details are submitted and then there is a code that converts the card data and merchant data into iso 8583 message and sends it to the (fake) issuer.

Here is the link to that code: https://github.com/alovak/cardflow-playground/blob/main/acquirer/iso8583/client.go#L56

In short,

1. You have to define the specification (how iso 8583 message fields are encoded) - usually you get such spec from the payment provider or a card network
2. You have to create the structures that will store data for the request (let’s say authorisation request aka 0100 message) and the response
3. You should build message by marshalling the data into the message
4. You should send the message and receive the response. In the playground project I mentioned above I use this Golang package to manage network connections, sending and receiving messages: https://github.com/moov-io/iso8583-connection

Answer (score -2):

you can use jpos in java or trx in c# to write the iso message programatically.